# how to grab property values from xml in batch file to create a condition to run files

Tags: xml, batch-file

How to use a batch file to grab property values from an xml file (build.xml) and set a condition to determine to run the xml file or not?

I want to grab the following values from the build.xml:

```
<property name="appbox1URL" value="http://10.111.111.111"/>
<property name="appbox2URL" value="http://10.222.222.222"/>
<property name="domainName" value="xxxG"/>
```

In my batch file I want to use those values to determine if we can make a call on running that build file. There is another set of values that is accepted as well to make the condition true, one for xxxG and another for Stage.

Psudeo in batch file

```
If appbox1URL = "http://10.111.111.111" and appbox2URL = "http://10.222.222.222" and domainName = "xxxG"
OR 
If appbox1URL = "http://10.111.111.000" and appbox2URL = "http://10.222.222.000" and domainName = "Stage"
THEN
call ant -buildfile "D:\xxx\Trunk\build.xml"
```

How is this suppose to be coded in the batch file?

```
directory of build.xml - "D:\xxx\Trunk\build.xml"
directory of batchfile.bat - "D:\xxx\Trunk\Batch\batchfile.bat"
```

Comment: Consider xproc or xmlsh or ant. If you use a general-purpose shell script for this, there's a great danger you will end up parsing the XML file multiple times - or even worse, loading the Java VM multiple times. Alternatively, put the control logic in XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [**`xpath.bat`**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) (it should be in the same directory as the following script):

```
:: Set relative path here if needed
set "xmlFile=D:\xxx\Trunk\build.xml"


for /f "usebackq delims=* tokens=" %%a in (`xpath.bat "%xmlFile%" "//property[@name='appbox1URL']/@value" `) do set "appbox1URL=%%a"

for /f "usebackq delims=* tokens=" %%a in (`xpath.bat t.xml "//property[@name='appbox2URL']/@value" `) do set "appbox2URL=%%a"

for /f "usebackq delims=* tokens=" %%a in (`xpath.bat t.xml "//property[@name='domainName']/@value" `) do set "domainName=%%a"

if /i "%appbox1URL%" equ "http://10.222.222.222" if /i "%appbox2URL%" equ "http://10.222.222.000" if /i "%domainName%" equ "xxxG" (
   call ant -buildfile "D:\xxx\Trunk\build.xml"
)

if /i "%appbox1URL%" equ "http://10.222.222.222" if /i "%appbox2URL%" equ "http://10.222.222.000" if /i "%domainName%" equ "OtherEnvironment" (
   call ant -buildfile "D:\xxx\Trunk\build.xml"
)
```